# Save rotated image using php with jquery-rotate plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, rotation

I want to save my rotated image to a file, but I don't know how...

I'm using jquery-rotate plugin to rotate my image, here's my javascript:

```
   <script>
    $(function() {                                 
         var rotation = 0;                            
         $("#left").click(function() {
             rotation = (rotation -90) % 360; 
             $("#spin-pic").rotate(rotation);
         });
         $("#right").click(function() {
             rotation = (rotation + 90) % 360;
             $("#spin-pic").rotate(rotation);
         });

    });
       </script>
```

Html:

```
<input type="submit" id="left"> 
<input type="submit" id="right"> 
<img src="something.jpg" id="spin-pic">
```

Please help, thank you:)

Comment: what r you trying to do??

Comment: Save rotated image to a file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: I couldn't get it to work... Do I have to add "name" to my image src?

Comment: look you want to save variable in file from javascript right? .. So you have to use $.ajax or $.post in jquery .. with that you can pass your image details to php .. and in php save variables to the file you want .. now you want to search for how to use ajax with php .. Good luck

Comment: The examples you gave me are all to do with box/text items... I couldn't find how to save the rotated image anywhere...